# Database (BE) design for manufacturing with assemblies and product hierarchy

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Our company manufactures shoes and I'm given a task to make a FE & BE for it. I decided to make the FE in MS Access for now (will switch to Django web app in 1-2 years most likely, once I get more familiar & comfortable with it) and BE is in MySQL for now.

Basically, our customer can order some product, say "shoeA" x 1080 in individual boxes (each pair has a box) and 24 of such boxes in a carton. Hence the structure for bill of materials (or assemblies... not sure of terminology here) would look like:

```
Order1 
    - Carton (size 24) x 45
        - Box (1 pair) x 24     -- (45 * 24 = 1080)
            - Packing paper x 1
            - shoeA x 1
    ...
```

But if we look at what shoeA consists of, it's more co-products and raw materials. Moreover, each item can come from different place (ie. warehouse) and can be assembled by different assembly (e.g. shoeA would not be assembled by the same assembly as where the packing is done). The problem is, that multiple assemblies do the same type of work (e.g. multiple packaging assemblies) and so we don't know which assembly will do what *at the time of the order* (e.g. order can come 6 months in advance and we will know which assembly will do what 2 months in advance).

To complicate things further, 2 assemblies of same 'type' (e.g. packaging assemblies) can require different materials even though they produce the same outcome. For instance our assembly in Turkey just needs the shoeA from us, they will provide the rest of the materials / co-products themselves (ie. boxes / packing paper etc). Of course this will reflect in price, but that's not the problem for now. The point is that both of these assemblies will produce **same** product in the end (ie. box with a shoe and paper in it).

How would one reflect this in back-end RDBMS? Currently I have:

[image: EER Schema]

Please ignore the attributes themselves (other than PK/FK) as they are just place holders until I get things finalised.

Answer (score 1):

I think the big problem you will run into is the possibility of subassemblies.  I.e. you may have three parts that get made into one assembly, and that assembly plus two other parts gets made into the shoe.

The way I have usually seen this handled is something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE part (
     id int autoincrement,
     is_assembly tinyint,
     ...
 );
 CREATE TABLE component (
     assembly_id int references part(id),
     component_id int references part(id),
     qty numeric, -- number used to make assembly
     equivalent_to int references part(id)
 );
```

Note that this sort of structure allows you to infinitely nest assemblies.

The equivalency problem can then be solved by adding the equivalent_to part which allows you to handle that.

note you need to track in and out of each part and subassembly separately because you no longer have a 1:1 mapping between parts in and assemblies out.

Comment: Thanks. What you described is my `Product` and `Product_Hierarchy` table I think. This would work great if everything is produced in same assembly line, but because it is not, I have hard time figuring out where should the `assembly` come into play. For example `p_1` consists of `p_1.1` and `p_1.2` (which can consist of other products), and that product `p_1` can come out as identical product from 2 different assemblies. Problem is that the first assembly required both `p_1.1` and `p_1.2` while the second one only requires `p_1.1` (will supply `p_1.2` themselves). How do you capture this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have alternate BOM's (bill of materials) where you have defined options.  It looks like your accounting for purchasing to send some items to vender some times and of course there would be a cost difference. The other options is to have a parts supplied list for a PO or Work Order (WO).  So on the fly you can vary the parts supplied.  If you are supporting an ERP you need to have a prefered method and a reason logic for the switch for example internal labor CAP.  If it is a purchasing option from multiple vendors you can use a dependent part.  In a ERP you need to know if there is a requirement for all the parts or only some.  If your ERP project for both parts and purchasing opt's for the single part Vendor you will have projected a oversupply.  Alternet BOMs also can have a vendor flag so vender A requires this for $$ and B requires no part for $$ then a cost based logic can work. Each option  can supply the same assembly but cost and workcenter load very.  In any case you need the logic to allow the PO or WO to very on the fly for what is really needed in case the vendor is out of a part and needs it supplied only this time or a WO is going to use a different option one time.   In any case you need to track what was used and what was produced for how many $ or time so the real cost of the Asm is known.

Fields added : BOM need option number, ranking preference, build or purchase

Purchase option. (vendor quotes can have the BOM option # show cost given that BOM option)

Build Options: Need Asm steps / time /machine or work center for each, ( bill of Labor table for make options) because different WC's could have different labor machine cost.
Cost of purchase option.

When creating WO or PO need to as which BOM Option to default.  Backflushing would not be a good option a manual pull/record should be done to keep inventory correct.